# When is an ApiController instance created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is a new instance of an ApiController created to service every request, or does it get "pooled" in some way to service subsequent requests?

The reason I ask is that I'm wondering about the lifetime of the member variables such as the DbContext member that the scaffolding puts in (but also my own members).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instance of ApiController is created new one on every HttpRequest.

Comment: Reference: *ApiController’s are instantiated by WebApi per request* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/07/16/dependency-injection-with-asp-net-web-api-and-autofac.aspx